# reference multiple controllers on a single lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, controller

I am working on a lightning component in which I am building a form. I already have a controller defined for it. However, within this component I wish to implement a custom controller that extends the lightning:fileUpload functionality. I have that code saved in a different apxc, called FileUploadHandler. Below is my code that defines the initial controller I need to use for the bulk of my component.

```
<aura:component controller="NewCtrl" implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
```

However, my helper has the following code `var action = component.get("c.deleteFile");` where deleteFile is in FileUploadHandler.apxc and not NewCtrl.apxc.

How can I ensure my helper references the methods from FileUploadHandler and not NewCtrl?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a new component to use a separate controller. In Aura, each component can have only a single controller. Otherwise, you would need to add a method to the component's controller to call the other controller.

Comment: what would that method to call the other controller look like?

Comment: @sfn00b Just something like `@AuraEnabled public static ResponsedeleteFile(String param) { return otherController.deletefile(param); }`. The exact details depend on the mehtod you're calling (parameters, name, etc), but it's just a normal method.

Comment: @sfn00b NewLLCRCaseCtrl.